# formal smoothness of a subfunctor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I need to study a deformation theory problem.

Take a ground scheme $S$ and fix an algebraically closed field $k$. Assume I defined a functor $F:Sch/S\rightarrow Sets$ which is formally smooth. I define a new subfunctor  $G:Sch/S\rightarrow Sets$ with a pointwise property, namely I fix a property $P$ and for $T\in Sch/S$ I define $G(T):=\{f\in F(T) \mbox{ such that for each }k\mbox{-point }t\in T\; f_t \mbox{ has the property }P \}$ and 
$Mor(G(T_1),G(T_2))=Mor(F(T_1),F(T_2))$
, where $f_t$ is the object induced by pullback $t\rightarrow T$, I am assuming I can restrict objects. Since artinian extensions do not change $k$-points, I would like to say that obstruction and deformation theory of $G$ is the same of $F$, is that correct? The example I have in mind is $F$ moduli functor for vector bundles on a curve and $G$ vector bundles satisfying a pointwise property.

Comment: "Take a ground scheme $S$ and fix an algebraically closed field $k$." It is somewhat unclear from the question whether this is necessary or not, but I assume this means "Fix an algebraically closed field $k$ and consider a ground scheme $S$ over $k$."

Comment: Also, the title of the question confuses me. Rather than "Is the obstruction and deformation theory of $G$ the same as $F$?" Are you asking the slightly different question, "Can I check formal smoothness of $G$ at a $k$ point by using $F$?"

Comment: @Matt the scheme $S$ is defined over $k$, then I define $G$ by having some property only at the $k$ points of $S$. I am asking for the formal smoothness of $G$ in general, i.e. I need artinian extensions over $S$, not only at $k$-points.

Comment: I don't believe something like this can be proved with this level of vagueness. It seems possible to be true in some specific cases (maybe the one you have in mind, which is still quite vague?), but for example what if the property $P$ is restrictive enough that the moduli space is of strictly less dimension? Certainly you can't just say "the deformation theory is the same" because $G(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)$ will not be the same as $F(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)$. Do we know this is an open subfunctor or anything?

Comment: @Matt actually my final goal was to prove the openess by using smoothness